# cvc4 mkconst from std::string in C++ api

Tags: c++, cvc4

I need to change "123" into a const in c++
what I coded as

```
ExprManager em;

Rational i = Rational("123",10);

Expr expri = em.mkConst(i);
```

or

```
Integer i = Integer("123", 10);

Expr epri = em.mkConst(Rational(i,1));
```

but I got some error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "___gmpq_canonicalize", referenced from:
>         __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>::canonicalize() in ex1-4f9d4d.o
>     "___gmpq_clear", referenced from:
>         __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>::~__gmp_expr() in ex1-4f9d4d.o
>     "___gmpz_clear", referenced from:
>         __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::~__gmp_expr() in ex1-4f9d4d.o
>     "___gmpz_init_set", referenced from:
>         __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]> const&, __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]> const&) in ex1-4f9d4d.o
>     "___gmpz_init_set_si", referenced from:
>         __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::init_si(long) in ex1-4f9d4d.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem above is caused by lack of GMP library. 
Installed GMP with "brew install gmp" on Mac.
compile the program with "-lgmp" flag

Problem solved.